# While renaming the column in a dataframe error occurred

Tags: python, pandas

```
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',skiprows=4)
GDP = GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name','Country'})

TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

There is a column in GDP with name Country Name I want to rename it to Country

Comment: Try using a list instead of a dictionary: `columns=['Country Name','Country']`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. This should fix it

```
GDP = GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name': 'Country'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Rename A and ABC to your columns name:

```
GDP=GDP.rename(columns={'A':'ABC'})
```